# Avoiding RandomVariate update with use of Locator

Tags: manipulate, random, locator

I am preparing an activity that simulates the response from a noisy spectrometer.  The function I use to generate the data has the form:

```
curve[a_, x_] := 
  a PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x] + 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.03]];
```

Which produces something like:

```
Plot[curve[1, x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

and I can get the coordinates using a right mouse button click on the plot.  The right mouse button works differently in a CDF than it does in a Notebook and I would like to ultimately turn this activity into a CDF-enabled web page.  My first attempt is to use a `Locator`

```
ControllerManipulate[
 Plot[curve[1, x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
  Epilog -> Inset[p, Scaled[{0.9, 0.9}]]], {p, Locator}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which does the job except that when I move the locator, the "noise" in my plot changes.  How do I modify my `curve` function so that I maintain the ability to generate a "unique" noise pattern each time `curve` is called but it does not continuously update when the end user moves a locator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with the `curve` function, but with your `ControllerManipulate` code. It is re-evaluating the entire argument (`Plot[...]`) every time the locator changes. You need to insert a `Dynamic[]` in the expression so that only that component of the expression gets updated when the locator moves. Use this:

```
ControllerManipulate[
    Plot[curve[1, x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
    Epilog -> Dynamic@Inset[p, Scaled[{0.9, 0.9}]]], {p, Locator}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Or memoize the curve:

```
ClearAll[curve];
curve[a_, x_] := curve[a, x] = (a PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x] + 
                 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.03]])

ControllerManipulate[Plot[curve[1, x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
                     Epilog -> Inset[p, Scaled[{0.9, 0.9}]]], {p, Locator}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In this particular activity, I do want to be able to generate the same curve with "different" noise - in a sense, simulating multiple trials of the same sample.  This might work if I memorize the random seed used for each run...